# Может ли значение свойства атома в LISP само иметь свойства и можно ли таким образом создать иерархию свойств атомов?

Tags: функциональное-программирование, lisp

Т.к. в LISP значение свойства атома может являться атомом, то может ли у этого значения свойства быть свое свойство и т.д. рекурсивно? Если да, то можно ли таким образом сделать иерархию хранения данных?

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под "свойством атома"? Почему бы просто не попробовать так сделать? :)

Comment: Думаю ваш вопрос не покрывается спецификацией и сугубо зависит от реализации Lisp'a. Укажите точней какой Lisp - Common Lisp, Ckojure, Scheme, AutoLisp, Elisp...